# Can privileges be set to allow certain users read/write access to a protected version?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, security

I have multiple versions of a database (some protected and some public). Would it be possible to allow some of the database users read/write access to the protected versions? I have read of protected versions; Any user may view the version, but only the owner or the geodatabase administrator may edit datasets in the version or the version itself.